# How to shorten the s3 presigned url using java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to shorten the s3 presigned url using java. Is there any aws service to shorten the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard AWS service that provides URL shortening.

However, you could [use AWS Lambda to create a URL Shortener](https://www.google.com/search?q=lambda+url+shortener).